# Define nonstandard expansion rule for lists

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have defined my own algebra using the unused operators $\oplus$ and $\otimes$. During evaluation, lists pop up which have the structure

```
{a__,{b_\[CirclePlus]c_},d__}
```

which I would like to expand to

```
{a__,b_,d__}\[CirclePlus]{a__,c_,d__}
```

I tried

```
{a_, {b_\[CirclePlus]c_}, d_} := {a, b, d}\[CirclePlus]{a, c, d}
```

but this returns the error

```
SetDelayed::shape: Lists {a__,{b_\[CirclePlus]c_},d__} and {a,b,d}\[CirclePlus]{a,c,d} are not the same shape.
```

How can I define such an expansion rule?

Comment: That's a specific problem with `List`.  It will work with most other heads, e.g., `list[a_, list[b_\[CirclePlus]c_], d_] := 
 list[a, b, d]\[CirclePlus]list[a, c, d]` is fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
CirclePlus /: {a__, b_\[CirclePlus]c_, d__} := {a, b, d}\[CirclePlus]{a, c, d}
```

Without the internal list though.